# Fluent Nhibernate Sqlite Linq where statement issue

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

```cs
return _session.Query<Artikel>()
    .Where(x => artikelReferences.Contains(x.ArtikelReference))
    .Select(x => new ArtikelStockInformation
    {
        ArtikelReference = x.ArtikelReference,
        QuantityOnStock = x.QuantityOnStock - x.QuantityReserved
    })
    .Where(x => x.QuantityOnStock > 0)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Genarated query works when I run it in sql db , but in code it returns empty list. I know that issue is with this greater than 0 - since when I set condition like `x.QuantityOnStock > x.QuantityReserved` it works.

Comment: `x.QuantityOnStock > x.QuantityReserved` is equivanant to `x.QuantityOnStock > 0` what is issue to use `x.QuantityOnStock > x.QuantityReserved` in where clause

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar well issue is that when it's is comparison with db fields works but when i set parameter to be compared lik 0 or any other number - it doesn't !

Comment: Have you tried `.Select().ToListAsync()` and then `.Select().ToListAsync().Where()`, because you are trying to create new set of type. I am not sure how nHibernate will interpret above query but you are trying to apply `Where` clause over new type. so I guess you need its list in memory. it is just a thought.

Comment: IQuerybble need first to be awited then I can use where statement , but that is not the point . I wanna have querry built the right way to be executed as sqlite statement

Comment: Where is `await`?

Comment: Is in method which is calling method that contains this part of code .. there is no issue with await. Just with comparing QuantityStock with 0

Comment: Not familiar with NHibernate, but why you guys never post generated SQL. It will be easier to understand what happened.